# Alchemy Language & French

Tags: ibm-watson

Hey Watson Community !

I would like to know, if Alchemy Language support French. I read a post about a release for the support of French Language in 2016.

Thank you for you answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

French is supported by Alchemy, it's documented here in the API : http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/#entities

> Supported languages: English, **French**, German, Italian, Portuguese, Russian, Spanish, Swedish

However:

- As of november 2016, French is only **partially** supported. Identification of keywords, entities, global [sentiments](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/alchemylanguage/sentiment-analysis) is available in french. Taxonomy is also available, but results are returned in english. Concepts and related sentiments are not available.
- the tests we did a couple of years ago tend to indicate the quality of the analysis was no way close to what you got with english. They may have improved since.